# How to position the origin of an object next to edges of another object with python

Tags: python, scripting

First I import a cone next to a box:

[image]

The cone has a good position in the X axis but not in the Y and Z axis.

So I translate it to this position :

[image]

Ideally, I want about 1 mm between the edges of the box and the center of the cone. I was wondering how can I translate the cone to that position (which is linked to the box) with a python script ?

Comment: is the origin of the box at its center ?

Comment: When I import the cone, both origins of the box and the cone are at the same position (0,0,0).

Comment: i mean at their geometry center

Comment: No, they are not, but after playing a bit with your script I obtain what I want, thanks !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If both objects origins are at their centers ; set their names in the script and run it :

```
import bpy

cone = bpy.data.objects['Cone']
box = bpy.data.objects['Cube']

edge = box.dimensions[2]/2 + box.location[2]
cone.location[2] = edge-0.1  #assuming 1BU->1cm
```